# Error in repmat function while reading mat file in matlab

Tags: matlab, yuv, mpeg

I'm trying mpeg codec in matlab where a .y4m file is encoded and decoded according to mpeg standards. Here the y4m file is loaded in to the project through the mat file 'fore'. 
I have created the mat file using the following code

```
mov = 'foreman.y4m';
 save fore mov
```

Further the code tries to replicate the data using the following code. nf is set to 10 i.e., number of frames to be processed.

```
load fore
% Movie is RGB, so get 4-D array (height, width, color component, frame #)
if nf == 0
    nf = length(mov);

end
movdata = repmat(uint8(0),[size(mov(1).cdata), nf]);
```

For this I got the following error

```
Improper index matrix reference.

Error in mpegproj>getmov (line 71)
```

Line 71 is

```
   movdata = repmat(uint8(0),[size(mov(1).cdata), nf]);
```

What might have gone wrong here..?

Comment: You saved the string 'foreman.y4m' in the mat file fore.mat. Is that what you wanted in the first step?

Comment: Even if i store just the filename 'foreman' in the mat file fore, I'm getting the same error..

Comment: In the mat file, I have just stored it like                                                       mov = 'foreman.y4m';
 save fore mov